# How to download code from RTC using command line?

Tags: rtc, alm

I need to download my source code from Rtc using command line ? Is there any command available to perform this activity?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a repository workspace, then the CLI command would be `scm load`.  Documentation is [here](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/load.html&scope=null).

To load into the current directory:

```
scm login -r https://server.com:9443/jazz -u user -P password -n repoNickname
scm load -r repoNickname "Workspace Name"
```

If the workspace name is not unique in the server, you can try the list workspace command to look for workspaces owned by you:

```
scm list workspaces -r repoNickname -c userName
```

The results will contain an alias which can be used in place of the workspace name in the load command.  Alternatively you can find the UUID for your workspace by finding your workspace in the web UI and taking note of the url which will contain the workspace UUID.